# Does the ( so called) " CAB" factoring method work for every quadratic trinomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, soft-question

Note : my qustion assumes one is dealing with a trinomial that admits of a factorization.

By "CAB " method I mean he following process:

when confronted with an expression of the form $Ax^2+Bx+C$

(1) compute the product $AC$

(2) find 2 numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that : $N_1\times N_2 = AC $ and $ N_1+N_2 = B$

(3) rewrite the original expression as $Ax^2+(N_1+N_2)x +C$

(4) develop this last expression and factor it by grouping

I roughly see why it works when the factorization to be reached has the form $(ax+b)(x+c)$ but it's much less cleear to me when it has the form $ ( ax+b)(cx+d)$.

Hence my question : does the method work when the factorization to be reached contains two binomials in which the "x-term" has a coefficient different from $1$ ( in each one of these two binomials) ?

Comment: Your two forms are really the same, because $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ can be rewritten in the second form, as $(acx+bc)(x+\frac{d}{c})$.

Comment: I know that this "CAB" method (that I would call the "ABC method") is taught in some secondary schools. It makes enter in lengthy proofs. It is not worth the value to discuss about it (indeed it become even lengthier when $A \ne 1$), whereas the standard method with computation of the roots through the computation of the discriminant is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding $N_1$ and $N_2$ is the same as finding the roots of the polynomial.

Indeed, the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ satisfy
$$
r_1+r_2=-\frac{B}{A},\qquad r_1r_2=\frac{C}{A}
$$
Set $N_1=-Ar_1$ and $N_2=-Ar_2$. Then
$$
N_1+N_2=-Ar_1-Ar_2=-A(r_1+r_2)=A\frac{B}{A}=B
$$
and
$$
N_1N_2=(-Ar_1)(-Ar_2)=A^2r_1r_2=A^2\frac{C}{A}=AC
$$
Conversely, given $N_1$ and $N_2$ with the properties you mention, it's easy to see that $r_1=-N_1/A,r_2=-N_2/A$ are the roots.

Note that the factorization can always be written as
$$
A(x-r_1)(x-r_2)
$$
and I don't find a real convenience in the “CAB method”.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it always works. To see why, suppose that the quadratic $Ax^2+Bx+C$ can be written as $(ax+b)(cx+d)$. If we expand $(ax+b)(cx+d)$, we get $(ac)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$. So $A=ac$, $B=ad+bc$, and $C=bd$. There is always a unique pair of numbers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $N_1 \cdot N_2=AC$ and $N_1+N_2=B$. Those two numbers are $ad$ and $bc$. Hence,
\begin{align}
Ax^2+Bx+C &= (ac)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd \\
&= (ac)x^2+(ad)x+(bc)x+bd \\
&= ax(cx+d)+b(cx+d) \\
&= (ax+b)(cx+d) \, .
\end{align}
If we split the middle term $B$ in a different way, then we get
\begin{align}
Ax^2+Bx+C &= (ac)x^2+(bc+ad)x+bd \\
&= (ac)x^2+(bc)x+(ad)x+bd \\
&= cx(ax+b)+d(ax+b) \\
&= (cx+d)(ax+b) \, ,
\end{align}
which is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes more intuitive if you get rid of $A$ by multiplying instead of by dividing:
$$\begin{align}A\times(Ax^2 + Bx + C)&=A^2x^2 + ABx + AC\\
&=(Ax)^2 + B(Ax) + AC
\end{align}$$

So factoring a quadratic with coefficients ${A,B,C}$ is equivalent to factoring one with coefficients ${1,B,AC}$.

Comment: Please, could you provide an example of how this fact can be turned into a method?